# How to check if IP has MAC address and if MAC = NULL, reboot

Tags: bash, networking, command-line, kernel

I have a machine that is used for network storage, that's it. Not a daily use machine. It's using LAN for network connection. For some unknown reason my MAC address is dropping from a machine on my local network. This becomes a problem in scenario when I'm remote, can't manual reboot and need to access the machine.

```
$ arp -a
xxxxxx.attlocal.net (192.168.1.145) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

The only way I can restore network connection is a manual reboot. So my proposed solution I'm asking for is placing locally adding bash script that checks if a specific IP has MAC address and if it does not, reboot the system. I would execute the script every 15 minutes via cron.

```
lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                              
No LSB modules are available.                                                                                                                                                                 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu                                                                                                                                                                        
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS                                                                                                                                                            
Release:        18.04                                                                                                                                                                         
Codename:       bionic
```

I've spent a significant amount of time trouble shooting the network issue and can't find the culprit. I know some would say this is a band aid to a bigger problem but regardless of the network issue I am still going to want this in place as it's serves as a fail safe in case of network loss.

Comment: Is the IP a local one (e.g. you are trying to license the machine) or another on the local network? In any case, the script you want seems a Very Bad™ idea.

Comment: @A.B thank you for your input so far. I've updated my description to include more details of my issue.

Comment: The `arp -a` is being performed from a different machine on the same LAN? Can you capture (say) `ip addr` on the storage server at / around the point where it stops responding to arp requests. (You might need an every-minute cron entry.) Has it lost its IP address too? Has the hardware and/or ethernet driver failed in some way?